# Past Tense in Editor Statistics

Tags: discussion

*Please advise me if this is better suited towards the main site. I posted the question here considering that it is about an ELU feature.*

---

[image]

My question relates to the Editor Statistics above.

My area of concern is the phrase

> -user- **had** 47 edit suggestions approved

To me, the sentence sounds very "terminated". What I mean by that is it makes it seem like the user has since deleted their account and I feel that the Editor Stats are providing a summary instead of an up-to-date statistic/record.

The below phrase seems a much better fit:

> -user- **has had** 47 edit suggestions approved

This is also taking into consideration the fact that the Reviewer Stats use "has":

[image]

Is there a reason why "has" isn't, or shouldn't be, used?

Comment: It's only marginal, but you're right that 'has had' is more natural. But this should be raised at [meta.se].

Comment: I might as well point out that meta posts tagged [meta-tag:bug] or [meta-tag:feature-request], no matter what meta site they are on, are all aggregated into the same tracker that the SE developers look at.